# Where to download Spring.NET binary files?

Tags: spring.net

On the site http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring.NET is zip with spring.net project for visual studio 2010, but in bin folder, there is not all spring.net dll's. If I try to compile it for me, there is thousand errors! Where can I download only spring.net binary files without compiling? My app is in .net 3.5 so I need spring.net 3.5.

Comment: You should download Spring.NET-1.3.2.zip from the page you posted. The spring dlls are in the bin folder.

Comment: Yes, I did it but there is not all spring dlls, such as Spring.Core.dll!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download Spring.NET-1.3.2.zip contains a folder bin, you find a release and debug build for each .NET framework version starting from 1.1 e.g.:

> Spring.NET-1.3.2\Spring.NET\bin\net\4.0\release

The stated folder contains the following files, including Spring.Core.dll:

```
11.02.2011  12:58            28.672 Common.Logging.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           142.848 Spring.Aop.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           527.872 Spring.Aop.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           581.262 Spring.Aop.xml
02.08.2011  09:59           775.168 Spring.Core.dll
02.08.2011  09:59         2.530.816 Spring.Core.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59         2.528.372 Spring.Core.xml
02.08.2011  09:59           384.000 Spring.Data.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            76.288 Spring.Data.NHibernate20.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           228.864 Spring.Data.NHibernate20.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           357.551 Spring.Data.NHibernate20.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            92.160 Spring.Data.NHibernate21.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           286.208 Spring.Data.NHibernate21.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           390.763 Spring.Data.NHibernate21.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            92.160 Spring.Data.NHibernate30.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           286.208 Spring.Data.NHibernate30.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           390.763 Spring.Data.NHibernate30.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            92.160 Spring.Data.NHibernate31.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           286.208 Spring.Data.NHibernate31.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           390.763 Spring.Data.NHibernate31.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            92.160 Spring.Data.NHibernate32.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           286.208 Spring.Data.NHibernate32.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           390.763 Spring.Data.NHibernate32.xml
02.08.2011  09:59           708.096 Spring.Data.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           625.891 Spring.Data.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            56.320 Spring.Messaging.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           111.616 Spring.Messaging.Ems.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           331.264 Spring.Messaging.Ems.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           288.844 Spring.Messaging.Ems.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            99.840 Spring.Messaging.Nms.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           253.440 Spring.Messaging.Nms.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           258.943 Spring.Messaging.Nms.xml
02.08.2011  09:59           161.280 Spring.Messaging.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           158.267 Spring.Messaging.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            34.304 Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            99.840 Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           106.541 Spring.Scheduling.Quartz.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            85.504 Spring.Services.dll
02.08.2011  09:59           181.760 Spring.Services.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           108.514 Spring.Services.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            32.256 Spring.Template.Velocity.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            40.448 Spring.Template.Velocity.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59            40.669 Spring.Template.Velocity.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            14.848 Spring.Testing.Microsoft.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            34.304 Spring.Testing.Microsoft.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59            27.650 Spring.Testing.Microsoft.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            18.432 Spring.Testing.NUnit.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            42.496 Spring.Testing.NUnit.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59            33.520 Spring.Testing.NUnit.xml
02.08.2011  09:59           165.888 Spring.Web.dll
02.08.2011  09:59             7.680 Spring.Web.Extensions.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            13.824 Spring.Web.Extensions.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59             2.898 Spring.Web.Extensions.xml
02.08.2011  09:59            13.824 Spring.Web.Mvc.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            28.160 Spring.Web.Mvc.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59            13.851 Spring.Web.Mvc.xml
02.08.2011  09:59             8.704 Spring.Web.Mvc3.dll
02.08.2011  09:59            22.016 Spring.Web.Mvc3.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59            11.587 Spring.Web.Mvc3.xml
02.08.2011  09:59           540.160 Spring.Web.pdb
02.08.2011  09:59           504.443 Spring.Web.xml
```

Eventually you should try to redownload the zip file or check if the file you downloaded is broken by testing if the file hash is equal to the following SHA1 hash:

```
d5a6266627a1f57bea38e67a4f1f76707414787e  Spring.NET-1.3.2.zip
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not take a look to .net/4 folder becouse I am using .net 3.5. So do you thing that I can use spring.net .net 4 for .net 3.5 application? Becouse in folder .net/3.5 are dll's missing. And I checked sha1 hash, it's correct.

Comment: The .Net 4.0 .dll will not work when you target for 3.5 (newer CLR). You should use the .dll in the 2.0 folder (same CLR as 3.5). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx